# What is the best way to delete elements from a JSoup Document in Clojure (java mutable object interoperability)?

Tags: clojure, jsoup, clojure-java-interop

Complete beginner with Clojure. How do you access the mutated jsoup Document in Clojure? I have the code below where I would like to print out the changed html rather than the links that are being removed.

```
(defn get-page []
  (.get (org.jsoup.Jsoup/connect "https://example.com")))

(defn -main
  "Fetch the page, delete links, and print out the html of the modified page"
  [& args]
  (let [html (get-page)]
   (println (.remove (.select html "a[href]")))))
```

Comment: Don't print the result of `remove`, instead add another line within the `let`-form and `(println html)` (or whatever java-interop  you like).  `html` holds the object you are after.  Once you modified it, it holds the current state.

Comment: Thanks cfrick. That was it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@cfrick answered the question in a comment, so I'll just expand that into an example to make it more clear.

Let's change `-main` to print the value in `html` before and after it's changed

```
(defn -main
  "Fetch the page, delete links, and print out the html of the modified page"
  [& args]
  (let [html (get-page)]
    (println "html before modification")
    (println html)

    (.remove (.select html "a[href]"))

    (println "html after modification")
    (println html)))
```